# Adobe Air Mobile App: Responsive sizing of Elements

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I still have trouble understanding the possibilities of Scaling my UI in a responsive way in my Air Mobile App. On the web I'm familiar with it and the use of media-queries.

I dont want to scale my whole UI up and down or even stretch it (e.g: I use the camera in one DisplayObjectContainer, so this would be really bad for the performance to scale this.)

I currently go down the road defining all the container sizes by percent, but that is getting pretty ugly pretty fast as it leaves me with 68.95px values. I think this will get me in trouble one day as blocks appear not crisp anymore. If I round the values, I might have 1px gaps between Elements.

[Currently I have this Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXa5K.png). The idea is, to give every main Component a (maybe invisible) empty background-child. These can then deformed by width & height by any desire. The inner Elements of any Element (button, logo, etc) are not affected by the deformation of the bg and can then be arranged accordingly (as I now have position and size of this container - like in css).

But this does not feel like it is the right way.

Is there a magic lib/class I dont use currently and that allowes me to build in hard pixel for a defined setup and behaves appropriate when it comes to different stageWidths, DPI, etc?

What are your approaches for this problem?

Comment: I don't expect there is some "magic" solution to ever-changing UI size. You can, however, try using dynamic sizing by percent, but once you determine the boundaries, align everything by even pixels inside your UI components` resize event handlers.

Comment: In our projects we set objects sizes in millimeters. Then you could get param Capabilities.screenDPI and recount millimeter sizes to dots.

Comment: Ok, I guessed there were something like a CSS FlexBox Class everyone is using except me that makes layouting dead simple. So I will knit something myself. Thank you.

Comment: To me it's not really clear what specifically you are trying to accomplish. It appears you are using Flex which already has various ways to create "responsive" layouts, [including css media queries and application scaling](http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/tag/media-query).

Comment: Yeah, the first thing to do is to design and work in physical sizes.  That's what using density pixels is all about.  Just figuring out how to use dp between your device and your monitor will clear things up.  Once you can think of designing by phyiscal size, things get much easier.  Material Design has a lot of design solutions using density pixels.